# Background-size: cover not setting height of background image

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to get a background image to fill a div completely. Using

```
.class{
   background-image: url('img.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
 }
```

and (`.row` is from Foundation 6)

```
<div class="row columns">
  <div class="class">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The image extends across the width of the container, however the height is only about 23px, presumably the line height of the `&nbsp;`. How can I get his image's height to be the full height of the image with at the width set by `cover`?

Comment: background-color works?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj If I replace background-image with background-color, the color fills the same space as the image was

Comment: Then it's because your `.class` element does not have the height that you are expecting. It's only the padding of `.row` that you see. Try adding a height e.g. `height: 100px;` to your `.class`.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Yes, I can add a min-height and it sort of cures the problem, but it will crop some of the picture still if I look at it on different sized screens. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's expected when using `cover`. You can use `contain` if you do not want part of image to be cut-off, but you may get empty spaces around your image in that case. You need to decide according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am new in Foundation 6, but If you want to fill all the div and adjust with the width and height: I use this code for the background and also work direct in div:(This is from: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

```
.class {

background: url(demo.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

}
```

Also, if you want to specify background size, used:

```
background-size: 80px 60px;
```

You can used:

```
@media screen {}
```

If you want to adjust the background or any part of the css class, base on the size of the screen

Important, check the: `margin:0px; or padding:0px;`

Let me know if this help you or if you need something more specific.